# getting string and numbers

Tags: c#, string

I got a string

```
string newString = "[17, Appliance]";
```

how can I put the `17` and `Appliance` in two separate variables while ignoring the `,` and the `[` and `]`?

I tried looping though it but the loop doesn't stop when it reaches the `,`, not to mention it separated 1 & 7 instead of reading it as 17.

Comment: You could use `String.Replace` to remove the square brackets, then `String.Split` with `, ` as the separator...

Comment: You don't have to do this character by character. Look up the docs on string.Length, string.SubString and string.Split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most performant method, but I'd go with it for ease of understanding.

```
string newString = "[17, Appliance]";   
newString = newString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]",""); // Remove the square brackets   
string[] results = newString.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Split the string

// If your string is always going to contain one number and one string:
int num1 = int.Parse(results[0]);
string string1 = results[1];
```

You'd want to include some validation to ensure your first element is indeed a number (use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), and that there are indeed two elements returned after you split the string.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your answer, but what if the entry is like this:
"[19, Oven Toaster]", as I see in your code(not yet tried), it will make the second element into "OvenToaster".

Comment: @BinurikiClieanJay No, it won't. It doesn't `Trim` the spaces, so no, it will return "Oven Toaster". [Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lMEdc7) for you to play with different types of input values. I've included a tiny bit of validation there to make sure `int.Parse` will not throw an exception if you've input a non-number, but other than that, the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could use this:

```
newString.Split(new[] {'[', ']', ' ', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: this is advance format for me, but in case the end user accidentally or intentionally put "," in between the letters of the second element (i.e., "[18, Va,e]"), this might destroy my database that I'm updating, so I'll just add this to my tools and hope to use it in other cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is another option, even though I wouldn't go with it, especially if you might have more than one `[something, anothersomething]` in the string.

But there you go:

```
string newString = "assuming you might [17, Appliance] have it like this";
int first = newString.IndexOf('[')+1; // location of first after the `[`
int last =  newString.IndexOf(']');   // location of last before the ']'
var parts = newString.Substring(first, last-first).Split(','); // an array of 2
var int_bit = parts.First ().Trim();   // you could also go with parts[0]
var string_bit = parts.Last ().Trim(); // and parts[1]
```